# How can I render a LibGDX modelInstance on Vuforia AR library?

Tags: java, libgdx, augmented-reality, vuforia

I know most questions on the community should  be done with at least some code. But I´m totally lost here, I don´t even know where to start. What I want to do is use the Vuforia AR Library to render LibGDX 3D modelInstances. However, I don't know how can I make Vuforia render the modelInstances or use a libGDX camera as it´s camera.

I've done external research but I have not been able to find useful information. Is there anyone who can help me get started with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. So I finfally managed to combine both libraries. I´m not sure if what I´m doing is the most efficient way of working but it has worked for me.

First of all I´m basing myself on the Sample Apps from Vuforia. Specifically using the FrameMarkers example.

I opened an empty LibGDX project, imported the Vuforia jar and copied the SampleApplicationControl, SampleApplicationException, SampleApplicationGLView, SampleApplicationSession, FrameMarkerRenderer and FrameMarker.

Next, I created some attributes on the AndroidLauncher class of LibGDX and initialized all the Vuforia Stuff:

```
public class AndroidLauncher extends AndroidApplication implements SampleApplicationControl{
    private static final String LOGTAG = "FrameMarkers";


    // Our OpenGL view:
    public SampleApplicationGLView mGlView;
    public SampleApplicationSession vuforiaAppSession;
    // Our renderer:
    public FrameMarkerRenderer mRenderer;
    MyGDX gdxRender;
    // The textures we will use for rendering:
    public Vector<Texture> mTextures;
    public RelativeLayout mUILayout;

    public Marker dataSet[];

    public GestureDetector mGestureDetector;


    public LoadingDialogHandler loadingDialogHandler = new LoadingDialogHandler(
        this);

    // Alert Dialog used to display SDK errors
    private AlertDialog mErrorDialog;

    boolean mIsDroidDevice = false;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        vuforiaAppSession = new SampleApplicationSession(this);
        vuforiaAppSession.setmActivity(this);
        AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new      AndroidApplicationConfiguration();


        // Load any sample specific textures:
        mTextures = new Vector<Texture>();
        loadTextures();
        startLoadingAnimation();
        vuforiaAppSession.initAR(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        gdxRender = new MyGDX (vuforiaAppSession);
        gdxRender.setTextures(mTextures);
        initialize(gdxRender, config);

        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new GestureListener());

        mIsDroidDevice = android.os.Build.MODEL.toLowerCase().startsWith(
            "droid");    
}
```

I needed to set the activity so I created the `setmActivity()` on the SampleApplicationSession.

After that I implemented the Libgdx ApplicationAdapter class and passed the vuforiaAppSession as an attribute to access all the stuff I initialized.

```
public class MyGDX extends ApplicationAdapter  {
    ModelInstance modelInstanceHouse;
    private AnimationController controller;
    Matrix4 lastTransformCube;
    // Constants:
    static private float kLetterScale = 25.0f;
    static private float kLetterTranslate = 25.0f;
    // OpenGL ES 2.0 specific:
    private static final String LOGTAG = "FrameMarkerRenderer";
    private int shaderProgramID = 0;
    private Vector<com.mygdx.robot.Texture> mTextures;
    //SampleApplicationSession vuforiaAppSession;
    PerspectiveCamera cam;
    ModelBuilder modelBuilder;
    Model model;
    ModelInstance instance;
    ModelBatch modelBatch;
    static boolean render;
    public SampleApplicationSession vuforiaAppSession;

    public MyGDX ( SampleApplicationSession vuforiaAppSession){
        super();
        this.vuforiaAppSession = vuforiaAppSession;

    }
```

The last important thing to keep in mind is the `render()` method. I based myself on the the render method of the FrameMarkerRenderer. It has a boolean that gets activated when the camera starts. So I simple changed the variable both on the vuforia AR initialization and the `render()` method. I had to put the camera on and identity matrix and multiply the model by the modelViewMatrix.

```
@Override
public void render() {
    if (render) {
        // Clear color and depth buffer
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        // Get the state from Vuforia and mark the beginning of a rendering
        // section
        State state = Renderer.getInstance().begin();
        // Explicitly render the Video Background
        Renderer.getInstance().drawVideoBackground();

        GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

        // We must detect if background reflection is active and adjust the
        // culling direction.
        // If the reflection is active, this means the post matrix has been
        // reflected as well,
        // therefore standard counter clockwise face culling will result in
        // "inside out" models.
        GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_CULL_FACE);
        GLES20.glCullFace(GLES20.GL_BACK);
        cam.update();
        modelBatch.begin(cam);

        if (Renderer.getInstance().getVideoBackgroundConfig().getReflection() == VIDEO_BACKGROUND_REFLECTION.VIDEO_BACKGROUND_REFLECTION_ON)

                        GLES20.glFrontFace(GLES20.GL_CW);  // Front camera
        else
            GLES20.glFrontFace(GLES20.GL_CCW);   // Back camera

        // Set the viewport
        int[] viewport = vuforiaAppSession.getViewport();
        GLES20.glViewport(viewport[0], viewport[1], viewport[2], viewport[3]);

        // Did we find any trackables this frame?
        for (int tIdx = 0; tIdx < state.getNumTrackableResults(); tIdx++)
        {
            // Get the trackable:
            TrackableResult trackableResult = state.getTrackableResult(tIdx);
            float[] modelViewMatrix = Tool.convertPose2GLMatrix(
                    trackableResult.getPose()).getData();

            // Choose the texture based on the target name:
            int textureIndex = 0;

            // Check the type of the trackable:
            assert (trackableResult.getType() == MarkerTracker.getClassType());
            MarkerResult markerResult = (MarkerResult) (trackableResult);
            Marker marker = (Marker) markerResult.getTrackable();
            textureIndex = marker.getMarkerId();
            float[] modelViewProjection = new float[16];
            Matrix.translateM(modelViewMatrix, 0, -kLetterTranslate, -kLetterTranslate, 0.f);
            Matrix.scaleM(modelViewMatrix, 0, kLetterScale, kLetterScale, kLetterScale);
            Matrix.multiplyMM(modelViewProjection, 0, vuforiaAppSession.getProjectionMatrix().getData(), 0, modelViewMatrix, 0);
            SampleUtils.checkGLError("FrameMarkers render frame");
            cam.view.idt();
            cam.projection.idt();
            cam.combined.idt();
            Matrix4 temp3 = new Matrix4(modelViewProjection);
            modelInstanceHouse.transform.set(temp3);
            modelInstanceHouse.transform.scale(0.05f, 0.05f, 0.05f);
            controller.update(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
            modelBatch.render(modelInstanceHouse);
        }
        GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        modelBatch.end();

}
```

It´s a lot of code, but I hope it helps the people that try to start integrating both libraries. I don´t think this is efficient but it´s the only solution I´ve come with.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that I am not versed in Vuforia AR specifically, but the question has gone unanswered for a while, so I will give it a shot.

---

The Camera in LibGDX is essentially just a wrapper for two 4x4 matrices, the view matrix `Camera#view`, and the projection matrix `Camer#projection` (there is another Matrix, the model matrix, used for world space transformations, however I believe [but am not 100% certain] that in LibGDX, this matrix is already incorporated into the view matrix [so `Camera#view` is actually the model-view matrix]).

Anyway, following on from this, unless there is a simpler solution that I am not aware of, you should be able to use these underlying matrices to deal with projections between the the Vuforia and LibGDX apis.

*(recommended further reading: Model, View, Projection matrices in 3D graphics)*

---

Next is rendering LibGDX 3D ModelInstances using Vuforia. A general solution to this problem, would be to convert the ModelInstance into something that Vuforia can recognize. This would be done by taking the mesh/vertex data represented by the LibGDX model, and feeding it directly into Vuforia.

IMO, the best way of going about this, would be to use a a core representation of the model data which can easily be given to both Vuforia and LibGDX (for example, a certain file format that both can recognize, or as raw FloatBuffers which should be easy to wrap up and give to either API). For reference, LibGDX stores models as vertex information in a collection of FloatBuffers, accessible through `Model#meshes` or `ModelInstance#model#meshes`.

Answer (score 0):

Pablo's answer is pretty good, however, if you are interested in a bit different approach (Calling Vuforia from LibGDX, not the other way) and a more complete example, here is a [github repo](https://github.com/daemontus/VuforiaLibGDX) with a simple 3D model renderer.